# ScalaARM error - value filter is not a member of ManagedResource

Tags: scala, scala-arm

Following the example on the ScalaARM homepage I wrote this:

```
for ( ir: IndexReader <- managed(DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(file)))) { ... }
```

(Open a lucene IndexReader)

however I get this compilation error:

> Error:(34, 45) Play 2 Compiler:  Indexer.scala:34: value filter is not
>   a member of
>   resource.ManagedResource[org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader]
>                for ( ir: IndexReader <- managed(DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(file)))) {

Can someone explain what is happening here?
                                             ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems the problem was the return type of the call to managed. I dropped the IndexReader type and it's fine now:

```
for ( ir <- managed(DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(file)))) { ... }
```